# Insert into one database table that has a relationship with another

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to insert a row into the Operator table shown below.

[image: Picture of database tables]

The database tables has a property of Operator.ID -> Alert.OperatorID

This is where I have gotten to so far:

```cs
using (AlertsDataContext db = new AlertsDataContext())
{
    Email email = new Email
    {
        emailAdddress = emailAddress
    };

    db.Operators.InsertOnSubmit(email);
}
```

I get an error on `(email)` saying it cannot convertbetween Email and Operator.  The ID column of Operator auto-increments.

How I insert just into the Operator table using LINQ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the Operator class instead of Email?

Comment: do you want to create new record for **operator** table ?

Comment: yes, I just changed the class to Operator and now I get the error 'Operator is a type which is not valid in the given context'

Comment: using (AlertsDataContext db = new AlertsDataContext())
{
        db.Operators.add(new Operator(){emailAdddress = emailAddress});
}

Comment: use the above code

Comment: That worked although I dont know why mine didnt.